# Change file directory in SharePoint using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and started doing projects with it. Currently, I have managed to copy files from SharePoint to ADLS. After copying, I would like to move the file in SharePoint to Archive folder using ADF but not successful.

So for example, my file is in "Shared Documents/latestfile/test.xlsx". After copying into ADLS, i would like to shift the file to "Shared Documents/Archive/test.xlsx"

Would kindly need some help in doing so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ShairPoint as a Sink is not yet support by Azure Data Factory.

[image]

Please refer the Docs to understand the Azure Data Factory connector overview, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores).

You can try to leverage SharePoint APIs to achieve same, mentioned here: REST call to move a file/folder to another location | [Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152936/rest-call-to-move-a-file-folder-to-another-location)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can i check what should i input for the Header and Body when calling the SharePoint API moveTo?